# Credit Score Limit

Tags: credit-score

Someone just tell me what was the *minimum* and *maximum* credit score!

Is there any difference in the credit score for **individual** and an **organisation's** credit score?

Comment: Which country is this about?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Flux 
This isn't specific to any countries. Worldwide probably!

Comment: @Community 
This isn't an issue or report.
I just wanted to know the limit. A general knowledge about the credit score to be specific.

Comment: There is no international standard. In the US you want the number to be high, in Germany you want it low.

Answer (score 1):

I am in the United States. I have always heard that the maximum score was 850. I have seen stories about how people hit he Maximum score of 850. Over the years each credit card that I had added the feature that showed you your credit score. They tended to agree within one or two points.

But then I noticed that one card had a range that went up to 900. The others still have an upper limit of 850.

The problem is that the term credit score is generic. And even in the United States when they use the term FICO with the trademark symbol after it doesn't mean they are quoting the same scoring algorithm. All my credit scores available on the credit card websites claim they are FICO scores.

On the [FICO website there is the list of scores available](https://www.myfico.com/credit-education/credit-scores/fico-score-versions), it was much longer than I imagined. There are multiple ones used by credit card companies, auto lenders, and mortgage lenders. Even the big three credit reporting bureaus in the US use different versions of the scores.

I noticed that on the FICO website they show a range of scores and they don't mention the minimum, they say less then than 580, and for Exceptional they say 800+.

In other countries there are could be many other companies providing the service.

Most people only deal with individual credit scores. How lenders evaluate the credit worthiness of a business is beyond my experience.

You will have to check with the credit scoring company in your country. You could contact your banker, lender, or credit card company to see what they use. Then you can figure out the range of scores.